# Spyder permission error

Tags: spyder

I created virtual environment test and installed spyder in that environment
activated and tested

```
source activate test 

 conda info -e
# conda environments:
#
bin                      /home/myname/anaconda3/envs/bin
conda-meta               /home/myname/anaconda3/envs/conda-meta
include                  /home/myname/anaconda3/envs/include
lib                      /home/myname/anaconda3/envs/lib
share                    /home/myname/anaconda3/envs/share
ssl                      /home/myname/anaconda3/envs/ssl
test                  *  /home/myname/anaconda3/envs/test
root                     /home/myname/anaconda3
```

When I try to run spyder I get the Permission denied error. Can not figure out why

```
myname - mycomp - ~/anaconda3/envs/test
0 # spyder
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/myname/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 2998, in main
    mainwindow = run_spyder(app, options, args)
  File "/home/myname/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 2902, in run_spyder
    main.setup()
  File "/home/myname/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 1153, in setup
    self.setup_layout(default=False)
  File "/home/myname/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 1414, in setup_layout
    self.setup_default_layouts('default', settings)
  File "/home/myname/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 1593, in setup_default_layouts
    widget.toggle_view(True)
  File "/home/myname/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/plugins/ipythonconsole.py", line 677, in toggle_view
    self.create_new_client(give_focus=False)
  File "/home/myname/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/plugins/ipythonconsole.py", line 862, in create_new_client
    connection_file=self._new_connection_file(),
  File "/home/myname/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/plugins/ipythonconsole.py", line 1340, in _new_connection_file
    os.makedirs(jupyter_runtime_dir())
  File "/home/myname/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 231, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode, exist_ok)
  File "/home/myname/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 241, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/run/user/myname'
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make this directory

```
/run/user/myname
```

writable. Spyder needs to write some files in there, so if that directory is not writable it will fail with the error you're seeing.